# bash: want errors from piped commands going to stderr, not to screen

Tags: bash, redirect

In my script, If I want set a variable to the output of a command and avoid any errors from the command failing going to the screen, I can do something like:

```
var=$(command 2>/dev/null)
```

If I have commands piped together, i.e.

```
var=$(command1 | command2 | command3 2>/dev/null)
```

what's an elegant way to suppress any errors coming from any of the commands.  I don't mind if var doesn't get set, I just don't want the user to see the errors from these "lower level commands" on the screen; I want to test var separately after.

Here's an example with two, but I've got a chain of command so I don't want to echo the variable results every time into the next command.

```
  res=$(ls bogusfile | grep morebogus 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the whole pipeline in a group:

```
res=$( { ls bogusfile | grep morebogus; } 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `{}` to group multiple commands:

```
var=$( { command1 | command2 | command3; } 2>/dev/null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to redirect `stderr` for each command in the pipeline:

```
res=$(ls bogusfile 2>/dev/null | grep morebogus 2>/dev/null)
```

Or you could wrap everything in a subshell whose output is redirected:

```
res=$( (ls bogusfile | grep morebogus) 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, what's the difference between the 3 different answers, either using braces, or the two you pointed out?  Which is more efficient?

Comment: @Ray The parens, `()`, create a subshell.  The braces, `{}`, merely create a _list_ or _group_.  Groups are executed in the current shell which means that they are likely more efficient but, in most cases, the difference is likely small.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just redirect it for the entire script, using `exec 2>/dev/null`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

return 2>/dev/null # prevent sourcing

exec 3>&2 2>/dev/null 

# file descriptor 2 is directed to /dev/null for any commands here

exec 2>&3

# fd 2 is directed back to where it was originally for any commands here
```

> **Note**: This will prevent interactive output and displaying the prompt. So you can execute the script, but you shouldn't just run the commands in an interactive shell or source it without the initial return line. You also won't be able to use read normally without redirecting the file descriptor back